# C# Selenium Extract from Div and 2 nested Spans.

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to get the right syntax with either XPATH or CssSelector using C# to extract the dollar amount shown below:

```
<div class="a-column a-span3 a-text-right a-span-last a-color-price a-text-bold sc-value">
  <span class="a-size-base sc-price-sign">
    <span class="a-nowrap">$39.93</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried? How is the behavior of what you tried different from the behavior you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to match the element with the desired text in this case. Here is one of the approaches relying on more or less non-layout specific classes that have a relevant meaning:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".a-color-price > .sc-price-sign > span")).Text;
```

Comment: U don't know if the question was updated but there is not link there, i don't know where you have seen a.

Comment: @Roro ah, sure, not `a`, but `span` - updated the answer, please check.